# C++ Loop Through Array, Find Smallest

Tags: c++

I'm trying to find the smallest value in 3 different array but it's not turning out right I don't think. It never seems to return the middle array even if it is the smallest. It's always either 0 or 2. What seems to be my logic error?

```
int smallest;
for(int i = 1; i < 3; i++)
{
    if(queue[i].getCount() < queue[0].getCount())
      smallest = i;
    else
      smallest = 0;
}
```

Comment: You compare to the entry at position 0, instead of the current value of `queue[smallest].getCount()` in the loop. (After making the correction, don't forget to initialize `smallest` properly in the declaration.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the errors in your code, it's a little difficult to see what you are trying to do.

I would think you want something more like this:

```
int smallest = queue[0].getCount();
for(int i = 1; i < 3; i++)
{
    if(queue[i].getCount() < smallest)
        smallest = queue[i].getCount();
}
```

If you instead want the resulting index, try something like this:

```
int smallest = 0;
for(int i = 1; i < 3; i++)
{
    if(queue[i].getCount() < queue[smallest].getCount())
        smallest = i;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm actually getting the index of the smallest queue. Or The Index of the Queue with the least amount of objects in it.

Comment: I've added another version.